# How to extract Blu-ray audio without any conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, blu-ray, libav, pcm

As `avconv` (forked from `ffmpeg`) said, the format of Blu-ray audio stream is called `pcm_bluray`, but why most of the tutorials say using `-acodec pcm_s**le` flag (`**` depends on its sample rate)?

Are they the same? If not, how to extract Blu-ray audio without any conversion?

Answer (score 1):

> Are they the same?

Not exactly, I think Blu-ray PCM audio is specifically designed for multichannel audio with certain sampling rates. That means, there are multiple PCM audio streams laid out according to the Blu-ray audio format specification.

But still, it's in essence just PCM audio, so it is losslessly stored.

> If not, how to extract Blu-ray audio without any conversion?

If your input is labeled as `pcm_bluray`, you can try copying it to the output with `-c:a copy`. But I'm not sure if this will work.

Conversion to a "normal" PCM format like `-c:a pcm_s16le` should always work, though, and it'd introduce no audible loss. The only thing that may be changed in such a case is the bit depth (e.g. from 32 Bit to 16 Bit).